# Why won't my XAML interactivity behaviors work in a user control

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, uwp

I'm working on a UWP application that utilizes interactivity behaviors to open/close UI elements.

As a little back story my application previously used copy/pasted XAML for a customer selection bladeview and blades in all of the relevant views.

Within that XAML were interactivity behaviors/triggers that would close one blade and open another upon a button click that worked perfectly.

Given the mess that was copy pasting the same XAML all over the places I cleaned up that UI piece and moved it into it's own user control which I just managed to get to work the way I need it to with bindings and all. The only issue is that my interactivity behaviors/triggers no longer work now that they are part of a user control.

Here is the specific XAML that relates to the behviors/triggers within the button:

```
<Button x:Name="CreatNewCustomer"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Content="New Customer"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Height="45"
                            Background="#FF007ACC"
                            Width="auto"
                            Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                            Margin="5">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                                <core:ChangePropertyAction  TargetObject="NewCustomerBlade"
                                                            PropertyName="IsOpen"
                                                            Value="True" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Button>
```

Here is my entire user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myapp.Views.CustomerDatabaseControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="using:retailemployeetoolset.Views"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
         xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
         xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
         xmlns:models="using:myapp.Models"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="840"
         d:DesignWidth="1320">

<Grid x:Name="AddCustomerBlades">

    <controls:BladeView x:Name="CustomerSearchBladeview"
                        IsEnabled="True"
                        BladeMode="Fullscreen">
        <controls:BladeItem x:Name="SearchCustomerBlade"
                            Width="1325"
                            Background="#FF1E1E1E"
                            Height="712"
                            TitleBarVisibility="Collapsed"
                            IsOpen="True"
                            BorderThickness="5"
                            BorderBrush="#FF707070">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Height="65">
                    <TextBlock Text="Customers"
                               FontSize="38"
                               Margin="10"
                               Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                               Width="825" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Width="465">
                        <TextBlock Text="Search: "
                                   FontSize="28"
                                   Margin="5"
                                   Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                   Width="90"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="CustomerSearch"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 Height="46"
                                 Width="350"
                                 Margin="5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Margin="5"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button x:Name="CreatNewCustomer"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Content="New Customer"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Height="45"
                            Background="#FF007ACC"
                            Width="auto"
                            Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                            Margin="5">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                                <core:ChangePropertyAction  TargetObject="NewCustomerBlade"
                                                            PropertyName="IsOpen"
                                                            Value="True" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="CloseCustomerWindow"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Content="Close Window"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Height="45"
                            Background="#FF007ACC"
                            Width="auto"
                            Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                            Margin="5" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,5"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Width="1307">
                        <GridView Name="CustomerList"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerDatabase}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  Width="auto"
                                  Height="685"
                                  Background="#FF2E2B2B"
                                  BorderThickness="3"
                                  BorderBrush="#FF707070"
                                  Margin="10,0,8,0">
                            <GridView.Header>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Text="First Name"
                                               TextAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               Margin="7,0,0,1"
                                               Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                               Text="Last Name"
                                               TextAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               Margin="7,0,0,1"
                                               Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="2"
                                               Text="Enail"
                                               TextAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               Margin="7,0,0,1"
                                               Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="3"
                                               Text="Phone Number"
                                               TextAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               Margin="7,0,0,1"
                                               Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="4"
                                               Text="Organization"
                                               TextAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               Margin="7,0,0,1"
                                               Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" />
                                </Grid>
                            </GridView.Header>
                            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                                            Value="7,0,0,1" />
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Customer">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="254" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                                        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                                                BorderBrush="#FF575454"
                                                Grid.Column="0">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CustomerFirstName}"
                                                       Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                                       Width="auto"
                                                       Margin="0,8,0,-2"
                                                       TextAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                                                BorderBrush="#FF575454"
                                                Grid.Column="1">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CustomerLastName}"
                                                       Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                                       Width="auto"
                                                       Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                                       TextAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                                                BorderBrush="#FF575454"
                                                Grid.Column="2">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CustomerEmail}"
                                                       Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                                       Width="auto"
                                                       Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                                       TextAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                                                BorderBrush="#FF575454"
                                                Grid.Column="3">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CustomerPhoneNumber}"
                                                       Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                                       Width="auto"
                                                       TextAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                                                BorderBrush="#FF575454"
                                                Grid.Column="4">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind OrganizationName}"
                                                       Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                                       Width="auto"
                                                       TextAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:BladeItem>
        <controls:BladeItem x:Name="CustomerAddBlade"
                            Width="1320"
                            Background="#FF1E1E1E"
                            Height="835"
                            TitleBarVisibility="Collapsed"
                            IsOpen="False"
                            BorderThickness="5"
                            BorderBrush="#FF707070">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Add Customer"
                           FontSize="48"
                           Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                           Height="56"
                           Margin="15"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             Width="409">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Email Address:"
                                   FontSize="22"
                                   Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                   Height="36"
                                   Margin="3" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="EmailBox"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 Height="50"
                                 Margin="3" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="First Name:"
                                   FontSize="22"
                                   Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                   Height="36"
                                   Margin="3" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="FirstNameBox"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 Height="50"
                                 Margin="3" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Last Name:"
                                   FontSize="22"
                                   Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                   Height="36"
                                   Margin="3" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="LastNameBox"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 Height="50"
                                 Margin="3" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Phone Number:"
                                   FontSize="22"
                                   Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                   Height="36"
                                   Margin="3" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PhoneBox"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 Height="50"
                                 Margin="3" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="BusinessCustomerCheckbox"
                              Content="Business Customer"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              Height="21"
                              Margin="10"
                              Foreground="#FFCDCDCD" />
                    <StackPanel x:Name="OrgNamePanel"
                                Visibility="Visible"
                                Margin="10,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Organization Name:"
                                   FontSize="22"
                                   Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                                   Height="36"
                                   Margin="3" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="BusinessNameBox"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 Height="50"
                                 Margin="3" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button x:Name="AddNewCustomerButton"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Content="Add Customer"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Height="60"
                            Background="#FF007ACC"
                            Foreground="#FFCDCDCD"
                            Margin="20">

                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:BladeItem>
    </controls:BladeView>
</Grid>
```

Is there something that needs to be done differently when using behaviors within a user control? Or can they just not be used within a user control?

I could just create properties in the code behind for the user control to handle opening and closing my blades but that just feels like it's going to be sloppier and require a lot more code than the 8 lines of code needed to use behaviors.

**EDIT**:
Adding the exception I received in case someone else searches for a similar error.

"Cannot find a property named Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyPath on type String."

Comment: Actually I don't see where you defined NewCustomerBlade?

Comment: You're right, I just noticed that I changed the name of the blade and didn't update TargetObject="NewCustomerBlade". 

However, prior to your solution I was getting an exception that I'm no longer getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `TargetObject="NewCustomerBlade"` would work. Can you try `TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=NewCustomerBlade}"`?

You also need to put this behavior outside of the user control, where the `NewCustomerBlade` control is. Make sure the Button and the control are on the same page.

Comment: Any idea why the code worked without using {Binding ElementName=NewCustomerBlade} when it was located in a Page as opposed to a UserControl?

Comment: That tells me the behavior can handle name strings, so it must be using the visual tree helper to locate the element if TargetObject is a string, not an actual element.

Comment: That makes sense given the wording of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your event handler isn't getting resolved correctly. If your are specifying the click handler in a different class than your control, you can wire it up with x:bind.

Check out the following code taken from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c286f324-50fb-4641-a0d0-b36258de3847/uwp-xbind-event-handling-and-mvvm?forum=wpdevelop)

> ```
> <ComboBox x:Name="ColorComboBox"
>       ItemsSource="{x:Bind SettingsVM.Colors}"
>       SelectionChanged="{x:Bind SettingsVM.ColorDefinitionChanged(SelectedItem)}" />
>
> void ColorDefinitionChanged(ColorDefinition def)
> {
>    ...
> }
> ```

Comment: That link helped provide some context around binding, thank you.